# How to use reflection on parameterized trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, manifest, traits

The access on Manifest seems to be tricky from a trait in scala.

How could this code compile in scala ?

```
trait SomeTraitOf[+A] {

  def newInstanceOfA : A = /*  necessary code to make it work */

}
```

(Related, it works fine as a parametized class :

```
class SomeTraitOf[A : Manifest] {

  def newInstanceOfA(implicit m : Manifest[A]) : A =
     m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A] 

}
```

but not with a covariant type parameter (+A))

Edit : The real stuff

```
sealed trait RootPeerProxy[+A] extends Proxy {

  def peer: A
  def self = peer
  def peerManifest[B >: A](): Option[Manifest[B]]
  private[scalavaadin] def newInstance() : Option[A]
}

trait PeerProxy[+A] extends RootPeerProxy[A] {
  override def peerManifest[B >: A](): Option[Manifest[B]]
  override def peer(): A = this.newInstance match {
    case None => {throw new IllegalStateException("oups")} 
    case Some(a) => a
  }
  private[scalavaadin] override def newInstance() : Option[A] = peerManifest map { m =>    m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A] }
}
```

Since traits cannot provide manifest for the parametized trait, the class implementing the trait should, but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About covariance**:

Since `Manifest[A]` is invariant in the parameter `A`, you can't do what you want directly. The usual strategy is to weaken the return type,

```
trait SomeTraitOf[+A] {
  def newInstance[B >: A](implicit m: Manifest[B]): B = {
    m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[B]
  }
}
```

You can use the trait as follows,

```
class Parent
class Child extends Parent
val childBuilder = new SomeTraitOf[Child] {}
val parentBuilder: SomeTraitOf[Parent] = childBuilder
parentBuilder.newInstance // returns a Parent!
```

**About View Bounds**:

From your comment below, I guess you're also asking about "view bounds", which are just a concise way of declaring an implicit parameter. Your declaration

```
class SomeTraitOf[A : Manifest] { ...
```

basically translates to

```
class SomeTraitOf[A]()(implicit m0: Manifest[A]) { ....
```

Traits can't have view bounds because they can't take any (value) parameters. But that's not really a problem here, because in your example

```
class SomeTraitOf[A : Manifest] {
  def newInstanceOfA(implicit m : Manifest[A]) : A =
     m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A] 
}
```

you're not using the view bound! (You're using the parameter `m` instead.)  If you wanted to use the view bound, you could do it this way:

```
class SomeTraitOf[A : Manifest] {
  def newInstanceOfA : A =
     implicitly[Manifest[A]].erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[A] 
}
```

Comment: `class SomeTraitOf[+A : Manifest] {

  def newInstanceOfA[B >: A](implicit m : Manifest[B]) : B =
     m.erasure.newInstance.asInstanceOf[B] 

}` works fine, but trait does not carry manifest information.

Comment: Ok, I get it, I cannot use it directly in the trait, like  `def peer() : A = newInstance`, but it works fine outside.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: I am making some trait to Proxy an existing API (Vaadin) in Scala. I do not want to write tons of code, so, I may want to have a clean solution for default Peer constructor in a PeerProxy.

Comment: You can take a look if you want at other parts of the code here : https://github.com/un-jon/scala-vaadin/tree/master/core/src/main/scala/scala-vaadin

Comment: About view bound, my mistake, i wasn't using it correctly in this case.